# How to set the default language in code?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I want to set the default language during install to something other than English.
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A profile install hook that enables and sets Swedish.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function hook_install() {
  // Enable swedish.
  locale_add_language('sv');
  $languages = language_list();
  variable_set('language_default', $languages['sv']);
}
```

Since `language_default` is a variable, it could also be [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) managed.