# Creating a language in code

Tags: updating

I want to set create a language in PHP code (for example, using a [hook_update_n](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) implementation) so I can deploy and automate it.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module supports exporting languages.

Answering the question:

```
// Example language: fr.
$language = (object)array(
  'language' => 'fr',
  'name' => 'French',
  'native' => 'Français',
  'direction' => 0,
  'enabled' => 1,
  'plurals' => 0,
  'formula' => '',
  'domain' => '',
  'prefix' => 'fr',
  'weight' => 0,
);

locale_add_language($language->language,
  $language->name,
  $language->native,
  $language->direction,
  $language->domain,
  $language->prefix,
  $language->enabled);

// Additional params not implemented in locale_add_language().
db_update('languages')
  ->fields(array(
    'plurals' => $language->plurals,
    'formula' => $language->formula,
  ))
  ->condition('language', $language->language)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Originally an answer of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/48872/10086